# Where can I find the apron/towel worn by the America's Test Kitchen staff?

Tags: food-safety, cleaning

On America's Test Kitchen, I've seen them wearing a towel around their waist that is somehow attached to an apron.  Is there a name for this?  Or are they just somehow tucking the towel into a standard apron pocket?

This would be a great kitchen convenience--where can I buy an apron like this?  (Preferably only covering below the waist as shown on Becky below.)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The traditional butcher's apron tie is to wrap the strings of the apron around behind one's back, then back to the front to tie.  This provides a convenient place to put a tea towel or rag.

From the photos, this appears to be what the folks in the picture have done (Becky and Chris, IIRC).  When I worked in a deli on Long Island, this is how we tied our aprons.

Comment: And to answer the further question in the parentheses, you can simply fold your apron in half (folding the top behind the bottom) so it only covers below the waist, though why you'd want to do that I have no clue. Expensive pants, cheap top?

Comment: That is exactly what we did at the deli, the manager thought people looked silly with the full bib up.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the towel is affixed to the apron, it's just folded and hung through the apron's string. Notice that both of them tie their aprons in the front, not in back, leaving the extra wrapped bit where they are hanging the towels.

Most restaurant supplie stores have a variety of apron's available or you could just find them online by searching "waist apron"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might Becky might be tucking the towel into something like [this apron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008R48RSS).

[image]